# Select all choices in a ManyToManyField by default

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-suit

Is it possible somehow by default to choose all the choices within a select multiple generated by ManyToManyField in Django?

All new items that are added should have all choices selected upfront in the view (also when adding new items of `AnotherEntity`).

```
class AnotherEntity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class SomeEntity(models.Model): 
    anotherEntity = models.ManyToManyField(AnotherEntity)
```

In the example above i wish to have all  choices in `anotherEntity` selected in all new items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inherit `SelectMultiple` widget and override: 1)`render_option` to render all selected; 2) `render_options` control where we have render all selected and where as  default.

```
class CustomSelectMultiple(SelectMultiple):
    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        if not selected_choices:
            # there is CreatView and we have no selected choices - render all selected
            render_option = self.render_option
        else:
            # there is UpdateView and we have selected choices - render as default
            render_option = super(CustomSelectMultiple, self).render_option

        selected_choices = set(force_text(v) for v in selected_choices)
        output = []
        for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                output.append(format_html('<optgroup label="{0}">', force_text(option_value)))
                for option in option_label:
                    output.append(render_option(selected_choices, *option))
                output.append('</optgroup>')
            else:

                output.append(render_option(selected_choices, option_value, option_label))
        return '\n'.join(output)

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')

        return format_html('<option value="{0}"{1}>{2}</option>',
                           option_value,
                           selected_html,
                           force_text(option_label))
```

Then set widget to your field in form:

```
class SomeEntityModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeEntityModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.base_fields['anotherEntity'].widget = CustomSelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeEntity
```

Comment: But that will always display all values selected because I've removed `if option_value in selected_choices:` https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L525 so maybe you should do this by js or switch to default widget `SelectMultiple` in updateview

Comment: Interesting. Of course i want the saved result to be shown again, in case some are deselected.

Comment: What should `some_field` be?

Comment: updated answer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I tried this example, but my fields are not being selected.

Comment: Do you have set `form_class = SomeEntityModelForm` in your view? So it should set 'selected="selected"' to each option. I admit that smth can work wrong because I've not tested this). But this `I tried this example, but my fields are not being selected.` is not `programmer`'s answer :)

Comment: Its for the Admin, so basically i have applied this to the `form` variable in `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: Please see the full example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637564/pre-selecting-all-choices-in-multiple-select

Comment: I've found this in docs `If you define the Meta.model attribute on a ModelForm, you must also define the Meta.fields attribute (or the Meta.exclude attribute). However, ModelAdmin ignores this value, overriding it with the ModelAdmin.list_editable attribute.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form

Comment: If you have the solution, post it there and i will accept it!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides so you can remove `SomeEntityModelForm` and set widget in `ModelAdmin` in `formfield_overrides = { models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CustomSelectMultiple},}`

Comment: Interesting. Something is happening now, but i get following `NameError`: `global name 'chain' is not defined` on line `for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices): `

Comment: Didn't work for me until I realized  `super(SomeEntityModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
and `self.base_fields['anotherEntity'].widget = CustomSelectMultiple()` should be reversed: otherwise render_options is not called

Answer (score 0):

you can `override` save methos of model like this:

```
class SomeEntity(models.Model): 
    anotherEntity = models.ManyToManyField(AnotherEntity)    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = AnotherEntity.objects.all()
        for choice in choices:
            self.anotherentity.add(choice)
        super(SomeEntity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It will save all choices regardless of changes by the end user on rendered page

Comment: I only want the initial to be selected. If the user deselects it should remain so.