# Django admin ManyToManyField with all relations selected by default

Tags: django, admin, django-orm

In the admin I would like to have a ManyToMany field select all its relations by default. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try this (and read comments) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578266/select-all-choices-in-a-manytomanyfield-by-default/26578445#26578445