# React DRF Select All the Options in the ManytoMany field by default

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I am working on a project with React and DRF and currently have my models like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.Charfield(max_length = 15)
    
class Books(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    authors = models.ManytoManyField(Author)
```

I have my models setup correctly and am able to send data to backend correctly. However, what I need is - all the options in the ManytoManyfield to be selected by default. Currently, the option is displayed in the ManytoManyfield but it is not selected. I am not sure how to go about it. I have gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578266/select-all-choices-in-a-manytomanyfield-by-default) but am still not clear on this. Please guide me on how this is done. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "select all by default"? What's the desired output?

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for your interest. What I mean by "select all by default" is, suppose there are six Authors mapped to the Book, I want all the authors to be selected. Similar to holding the command button and selecting all Authors manually on the Django Admin Panel. Is there any property which would satisfy Multiselect = true.

Comment: But you want DRF to return that or in django admin?

Comment: I need it in the Django Admin

Answer (score 1):

Try with default:

**models.py**:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.Charfield(max_length = 15)

def allAuthor():
    authorList = Author.objects.all()
    return authorList

class Books(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    authors = models.ManytoManyField(Author,default=allAuthor)
```

Comment: Thanks, Pradip. I tried this approach and it did not solve the purpose. Is there any other possibility to solve this?

Comment: @Prashant It will work perfectly when new data create in Book table..